# Javascript event library 'unidentified'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have been working on a Javascript library for event handling. Here is some of the code:

```
01| (function(){
02|     var int,
03|         Jist = function(s){
04|             return new Jist.fn.init(s);
05|         };
06|     Jist.fn = Jist.prototype ={
07|         init : function(s){
08|             if(!s){
09|                 return this;
10|             }
11|             else{
12|                 this.length = 1;
13|                 if (typeof s === "object"){
14|                     this[0] = s;
15|                 }
16|                 else if(typeof s === "string"){
17|                     var obj;
18|                     obj = document.querySelectorAll(s);
19|                     this[0] = obj;
20|                     this.elem = this[0];
21|                 }
22|                 return this;
23|             }
24|         },
25|     };
26|     Jist.fx ={
27|         event : function(event,callback,state){
28|             var dummy = (state) ? false : state; 
29|             for(var i=0; i<this.elem.length; i++) {
30|                 this.elem[i].addEventListener(event,callback,dummy);
31|             }
32|             return this;
33|             },
34|     }
35|     Jist.fn.init.prototype = Jist.fn;
36|     Jist.fn.init.prototype = {
37|         print : function(txt){
38|             for(var i=0; i<this.elem.length; i++) {
39|                 this.elem[i].innerHTML = txt;
40|             }
41|             return this;
42|         },
43|         click : function(callback){
44|             Jist.fx.event("click",callback);
45|             return this;
46|         },
47|     };
48|     window.Jist = window._ = Jist;
49| })();
```

And then On my web page, here is what I have to test it out:

```
01| <div id="enter">Begin!</div>
02| <script>
03|    _("#enter").click(function(){
04|       _("#enter").print("It worked!");
05|    })
06| </script>
```

It seems like this should work, but instead I get an error that reads:

> 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating this.elem.length)[line 29 in the library]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just debug the line 29 (this.elem.length) and see what you get for 'this'. i hope the problem may be with that 'this'

Comment: `this[0] = s` and `this.elem = this[0]` don't look too good... What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Jist.fx.event("click",callback);` and it starts executing the `event` method `this` will be `Jist.fx` and it has no property named `elem` which the `event` method is trying to use when it references `this.elem.length`.  That causes the error you see.

Answer (score 0):

`this.elem` is out of function scope hence it returns undefined error, so instead of `this.elem.length` use `jist.elem.lengh` and check

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `event` method `this` does not refer to the object set you want, you can fix it using a [Function.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

You need to change the call to event registration method like

```
Jist.fx.event.call(this, "click", callback);
```

Also you need to make sure that the event registration code is called after the dom is loaded with the target element

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NFgeZ/)